# Can someone track vpn using via raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

If I make my own vpn using raspberry pi then can anyone track me?

I have made a vpn on raspberry pi using Pivpn so can someone or the Pivpn owner see my activity online?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. If you have a problem related to specific code that you are writing, please edit your question to include the code. Otherwise, you may want to ask your question over at the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation to help your question be understandable.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit confusing and we need more information to follow up.

A VPN works by sending all your data through an encrypted tunnel to another far away server.

However if your raspberry pi is at the same location you browse the internet from (such as your home) your ISP will still be able to detect the requests you are making as they will still be made from your IP address.

More detail on the question and who you are trying to stop tracking you would be useful.